# How can I add more than 5 widgets in a widget extension? the maximum number of WidgetBundle's widget cannot exceed 5

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

It seems that `WidgetBundle` has a maximum number limit, if it exceeds 5, a compile error will be reported: `Extra argument in call`.

But I have not seen such a description in any document, and no other developers mentioned this issue.

Does anyone have an idea?

```
@main
struct WidgetsBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        Widget1()
        Widget2()
        Widget3()
        Widget4()
        Widget5()
        Widget6() // Extra argument in call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am experiencing same error within `WidgetBundle`. If you are interested in having more than 5 widgets for the app, there is a workaround:

```
@main
struct WidgetKitExtension: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        Widget1()
        Widget2()
        Widget3()
        Widget4()
        Bundle2().body
    }
}

struct Bundle2: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        Widget5()
        Widget6()
        Widget7()
    }
}
```

Basically, you create second `WidgetBundle` and use it in your first one. I have verified that this works as of `Xcode 12.0.1`

Haven't tested submitting the app with more than 5 widgets though.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your answer. I tried and can even use a `Bundle3` in `Bundle2` to make more than 25 widgets. If the submission is approved, I will reply here.

Comment: The submission is approved by Apple. 

Answer (score 1):

For information, the limit of five widgets is because the `WidgetBundleBuilder` result builder only had versions of `buildBlock` for 1-5 entries.

You can see this limit by selecting the `WidgetBundleBuilder` in your code, right clicking and selecting "Jump to Definition". Scroll down a little and you will see overloads in SwiftUI for `buildBlock` going as high as five template parameters.

I just noticed that Xcode 14 / iOS 16 has raised this limit to ten entries: there are now `buildBlock` overloads going as high as ten template parameters.

This is a compile-time limitation. An Xcode 14 build using up to ten widgets in a single `WidgetBundleBuilder`'s `body` method now compiles and works when run on iOS 15 (I've not tried iOS 14). The workaround would still be required to exceed 10 widgets.